# How do I keep baby villagers babies in MCPE (2018)

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

In my map, I want to keep a baby villager a baby.

I already saw answers to this but I don’t get them. If anybody knows exactly how to keep a baby villager a baby, forever, in step by step, extremely detailed explanation.

I know you have to do something like @s or yourself and then put in some long command for age and it has to be negative.

Comment: /summon villager ~ ~ ~ {Profession:0,CareerLevel:1,Age:-1000000000,ForcedAge:-1000000000} That’s what I used that somebody else used

Comment: ForcedAge is currently buggy, and there isn't really a reason (that I can think of) that would require use of it.

Comment: Last I knew, NBT was not supported in MCPE.  I don't play PE, so I don't know for sure.

Answer (score 1):

```
/summon villager ~ ~ ~ {Age:-2147483648}
```

This will keep the villager a baby for about 3.5 years.

Comment: Oh, do I put that in that chat box or a command block because it says syntax error

Comment: And like do i put the coordinates in for the squiggle things or no

Comment: @Shadow This doesn’t work for MCPE (see my answer).

Answer (score 1):

Currently in Bedrock Edition, this is not possible as there is no `dataTag` argument in the `summon` command.

Source: [Commands/summon on Minecraft Gamepedia](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Commands/summon)